# when I record a macro, can I click other macros in the same worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with several macros which have the name of different subsidiary companies.

The spreadsheet will show financial information for one company when I click the macro with that company's name.

How do I make a macro to execute one and save the information, and then execute another one and save it, until all are saved?

I tried to record the process, but after I started recording, I couldn't click macro for any company. What is wrong with it?

Thank you for help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can call your makros one after another in VBA.

```
Private Sub btn_Click()
    Makro1
    Makro2
End Sub

Sub Makro1()
    'Do Stuff
End Sub

Sub Makro2()
    'Do Stuff
End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, _How do I make a macro to execute one and save the information, and then execute another one and save it, until all are saved?_